# How to format a heading in a javadoc comment?

Tags: java, javadoc

How can I format headings in a Javadoc comment such that they match the format of `@param`, `@return`, or `@throws`. I am *not* asking how to define my own keywords, rather how to have a bold face heading similar to them.

I have tried `<h1></h1>` but it looks terrible in the Javadoc-view of Eclipse, in particular the size is much larger. Is there an alternative, or is `<h1></h1>` the way to go?

```
/**
 * foo
 *
 * @param x foo
 * @return foo
 * @throws foo
 */
public int foo(int x) { return x; }
```

[image]

The screenshot is taken from Eclipse.

**Update**

I do not think that `<strong>` is sufficient, since it does not add line breaks:

```
/**
 * Introduction
 * 
 * <strong>Heading</strong>There is no line break.
 * <strong>Heading</strong>There is no line break.
 *
 * @param x foo
 * @return foo
 * @throws foo
 */
```

[image]

Comment: `<strong>foo</strong>` - note that the first sentence is generally bolded automatically (but you need a `.` after `foo`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just have a look at the generated Java Doc of the JAVA API, e.g. [SimpleDateFormat.parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) (have a look at the HTML source code).

They use a html description list for formatting and a `strong` CSS class to format the term. So do it the same:

```
/**
 * Introdcution
 * 
 * <dl>
 * <dt><span class="strong">Heading 1</span></dt><dd>There is a line break.</dd>
 * <dt><span class="strong">Heading 2</span></dt><dd>There is a line break.</dd>
 * </dl>
 *
 * @param x foo
 * @return foo
 * @throws foo
 */
```

Looks like this:

[image: JavaDoc screenshot]

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
/**
 * <strong>Heading</strong>There is no line break.
 * <br /> <strong>Heading</strong>There is no line break.
 *
 * @param x foo
 * @return foo
 * @throws foo
 */
public int foo(int x) { return x; }
```

Comment: should I put a `<br>` in front and after it to get the line breaks?

Comment: It will add single line break automatically.

Comment: For me, neither Eclipse javadoc-view nor the tooltip adds line breaks.

Comment: But in the image you attached, there is a line breake between 'foo' and Parameters.

Comment: This line break is there by default. `<strong>` does not change anything about the line breaks for me.

Comment: I disagree, it does not add line breaks.

Comment: If you need more than one line break than use <br />. Modified the answer.